# ethminer can not connect to geth RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, ethminer

Ethminer says:

```
JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
  m  10:47:22|ethminer  Getting work package...
  ✘  10:47:32|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  10:47:32|ethminer  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out
```

Ethminer was run with following options:

```
ethminer -G --opencl-device 0 -F http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

I've got a quadcore machine with 8Gig of RAM.
I'm sure that RPC is started:

```
> admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1",8545,"web3,net,eth,miner")
true
```

I tried to observe the traffic with tcptump, but is shows only SYNC packets from ethminer to geth. Looks like geth does not respond.

Some geth info:

```
> admin.chainSyncStatus
undefined

> web3.eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3990980,
  highestBlock: 3991101,
  knownStates: 8721073,
  pulledStates: 8714457,
  startingBlock: 3989781
}
```

Software:

Geth -- instance: Geth/v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5/linux-amd64/go1.8.3

Ethminer -- Genoil's ethminer 0.9.41-genoil-1.1.7